# Too much delay while sending object over UDP to server

Tags: java, udp

I'm getting 4 sec delay when sending objects over UDP. Working on small game and trying to implement multiplayer. For now just trying to synchronize movements of 2 balls on the screen. StartingPoint.java is my server(first player), that receiving serialized objects (coordinates). SecondPlayer.java is client that sending serialized objects to server. 
   When I'm moving my first object it appears 4 seconds later on different screen.

StartingPoint.java

```
@Override
public void run() {

    byte[] receiveData = new byte[256];
    byte[] sendData = new byte[256];
   // DatagramSocket socketS;
     try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(5000);
        System.out.println("Socket created on "+ port + " port");
    } catch (SocketException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    while(true){

        b1.update(this);
        b3.update();

        System.out.println("Starting server...");

        //// Receiving and deserializing object

            try {                   
                //socket.setSoTimeout(1000);
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                socket.receive(packet);

                 byte[] data = packet.getData();
                    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
                  //  socket.setSoTimeout(300);
                        b1 = (Ball) is.readObject();

            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        repaint();

        try {       Thread.sleep(17);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

SecondPlayer.java

```
@Override
public void run() {

    while(true){

        b.update();
        networkSend();

        repaint();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(17);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

public void networkSend(){

    // Serialize to a byte array
    try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ObjectOutputStream oo;
                oo = new ObjectOutputStream(bStream);
                oo.writeObject(b);
                oo.flush();
                oo.close();

                byte[] bufCar = bStream.toByteArray();

                //socket = new DatagramSocket();
                //socket.setSoTimeout(1000);
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(bufCar, bufCar.length, address, port);
                socket.send(packet);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the obvious stuff ...

Remove all the timeout calls.
Remove the Thread.Sleep() calls.

Have you tested just this code on its own?
How do you know its "slow"?

Are you sure the code that reacts to this isn't slow?

Why are you creating a new connection on every send ...

The process should be ...

1. create "connection" / stream reference.
2. send, send, send.
3. dispose.

It appears at a glance to be creating the stream references and buffers on every send ... creating that can be time consuming as there's a sort of negotiation / resolution process that needs to happen under the bonnet and of course the time spent creating objects in ram that you then just bin.

Do you have a garbage collection issue with this ... my thought is yes if you use this a lot?

I have a network client class that holds on to a stream and a buffer that when I call send gets reused.
I then have a second buffer for receiving which again is reused on every receive.

Much more efficient IMO.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Eliminated all the timeouts and there was another frame window with statistics. Works a lot better now with no delays.